# No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date. Done

Tags: .net-core, миграция, entity-framework-core

При работе с Entity возникли проблемы с миграциями. Я начал несложный WEB API проект. У меня есть две базы: тестовая и продакшен. При разработке я был подключен к тестовой базе. Добавлял модели, генерировал миграции, обновлял базу до этих миграций, добавлял в базу данные. Приведу ниже несколько команд:

`dotnet ef migrations add FirstMigration`

`dotnet ef database update`

То есть, я добавил несколько моделей, создал миграцию, в имени которой кратко отобразил, что именно она делает. Добавил данные, потестил, перешел к реализации следующей части приложения. Все было отлично, до тех пор, пока не возникла необходимость релиза приложения и подключения продакшен базы.

Для этого я создал файл `appsettings.Production.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Recipes" : "connection string here"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Установил connection string для продакшен базы данных. Установил переменную среды `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"`.

Далее я планировал выполнить все те миграции на продакшен базе, которые у меня отработали для девелопмент базы. Но тут то меня и ждал сюрприз:

После выполнения `dotnet ef database update` я получил это:

`No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
Done.` Почему так происходит? Погуглил, но все предлагают примерно следующее: удалить папку миграций, очистить базу данных и выполнить миграции снова. Это работает. Но это же бред! Что это за миграции такие тогда? Миграции ведь нужны для того, чтоб сохранить историю изменения базы данных. А так при каждом изменении мне нужно будет затирать базу. Так себе решение.

На всякий случай, я закреплю здесь свой ApplicationContext

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ApplicationContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Recipes");
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeStep> RecipeSteps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingridients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Advertising> Advertisings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FileModel> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeLike> RecipeLikes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeDislike> RecipeDislikes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

Миграции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как Entity понимает, что миграции уже выполнены? Я ведь подключаюсь к другой базе, а история миграций хранится в таблице `__EFMigrationsHistory`. Кстати, эта таблица создается пустой после вывода ошибки `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date. Done.`. 
Быть может я просто не понимаю процесса работы с Entity? Опишите, пожалуйста, ваш процесс, если вы работаете в схожем режиме (я имею в виду, тестовую и продакшен базу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело было в файле `.Designer.cs`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потеря этого файла ведет к описанной мою проблеме.